# IIS close one action in an application (close one controller)

Tags: c#, .net, iis, controller

I hope you good.

Sorry that I am new with IIS here is my case:

I have a project lets call that is TProd
I have `TProdController` and `TPRodTest` and that is alive in `https://..../TProd/TProdTest` and  `https://..../TProd/TProd`

I want to close the `https://..../TProd/TProd` how can i do that?

Edited: "Close" means I want to stop the request for the "TProd" method from IIS

I have tried "request Filtering", and a few thing but I could not.... any help please

I want to close just `https://..../TProd/TProd` from IIS I do not want to update the project and keeping alive the `https://..../TProd/TProdTest`

I solve my problem like this:
in IIS application pool I selected my application -> request Filter -> Headers
I added the specific header and the value that are unique for the Tprod Controllor methods

Comment: What do you mean by “close”? Prevent requests from being made to that URL?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. are you referring to close the "https://..../TProd/TProd" for this request? For example, when the client makes this request, it returns 404? If that's the case you can use url rewrite, If I misunderstand your requirement, please post more details information about your requirement.